# How can I temporarily unmask a password cell of a datagridviw?

Tags: c#, datagridview, masking

In my datagridview control I masked the password column like this:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  if (dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText=="Password" && e.Value != null)
  {
    e.Value = new String('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
  }
```

Now what I would like to do is some how click and hold down a mouse button on a specific cell and show the actual password for that cell, and when I release the button have it go back to being masked.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sir Bob, Try to check this site https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/109635/Create-Password-Column-in-DataGridView-using-C-and-VBNet-in-Windows-Application/

Comment: I have written a class that encrypts and decrypts the passwords. So in the table itself it is encrypted. When I bring it to display I decrypt it first and then place it on display.

Answer (score 0):

See the following

```
TextBox sampletxtbox = e.Control as TextBox;
if (sampletxtbox != null)
{
    sampletxtbox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
}
```

where `e` comes from the `EditingControlShowing` event. handle this event and cast it to a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little tricky trying to get it to work this way in a DataGridView.  I wasn't sure if the EditingControlShowing event was going to work for you, but if it does then you can cast the control as a TextBox and toggle the UseSystemPasswordChar as show in the answer above.  Here is a little functionality I put together.  You can create a test project and paste this in and play with it.
`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataGridView gv = new DataGridView();
        Controls.Add(gv);

        var buttonCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn()
        {
            Name = "colButton",
            HeaderText = "Show Password",
            UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
            Text = "Click"
        };
        gv.Columns.Add(buttonCol);

        var textCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            Name = "colPassword",
            HeaderText = "Password"
        };
        gv.Columns.Add(textCol);

        var hiddenTextCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            Name = "colHiddenPassword",
            Visible = false
        };
        gv.Columns.Add(hiddenTextCol);

        gv.Rows.Add();
        gv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        gv.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "********";
        gv.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "password";

        gv.CellMouseDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
        };

        gv.CellMouseUp += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = new String('*', gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Length);
        };
        gv.CellMouseLeave += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = new String('*', gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Length);
        };
    }
}
```

`
In this example I've put together a simple DataGridView with three columns, the first column is the button column, second column is the visible password column and the third column is the plain text hidden password column.

The DataGridView has three events being handled: CellMouseDown, CellMouseUp and CellMouseLeave.

The CellMouseDown will replace the hidden password with the plain text password and the CellMouseUp and CellMouseLeave will put in '*' characters up to the length of the plain text password as you have it originally.

Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions or concerns!